# Power BI Query Error - Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 3

Tags: networking, powerbi, days

I am new to Power BI Query.  I have written this query to be able to calculate networkdays:

```
(Created as date, Closed as date, Holiday as list) as number =>
let 
    ListDates = List.Dates (Created, Number.From (Closed-Created), #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    RemoveWeekends = List.Select(ListDates, each Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday)< 5),
    RemoveHolidays = List.RemoveItems (RemoveWeekends,Holiday),
    CountDays=List.Count(RemoveHolidays)
in 
    CountDays
```

It has returned an error saying:

```
Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 3.
Details:
    Pattern=
    Arguments=[List]
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint what this error means and where I may have messed up the query?

Comment: Are you certain the error is coming from the function you posted?  Perhaps it is coming from when you call the function in your main query, and you omitted the `Holidays` argument. Using your function, and entering some mock data, it does not return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works as you intend. The error will be caused if you invoke the function by only specifying 2 of the 3 required arguments (`Created`, `Closed` and `Holiday`)

If you want to make your Holiday list an optional argument, you can adjust your function query like this, which will now work when only the first two arguments are specified;

```
(Created as date, Closed as date, optional Holiday as list) as number =>
let 
    ListDates = List.Dates (Created, Number.From (Closed-Created), #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    RemoveWeekends = List.Select(ListDates, each Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday)<5),
    RemoveHolidays = try List.RemoveItems(RemoveWeekends,Holiday) otherwise RemoveWeekends,
    CountDays = List.Count(RemoveHolidays)
in 
    CountDays
```